# Cognito user pool Authentication via API Gateway + Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I'm developing a serverless `API using Cognito + API Gateway + Lambda + S3`, and I have some doubts about the implementation of the authentication via API. I don't want my customer use the `AWS SDK` to login in my system, I want that he login using my API and this API verify the identities from user. I did not found any examples of how can I do that and I'm posting here my doubt to verify if anyone already did it.

The workflow basically is:

**Client -> Login via API (https://.......amazon.com/v1/login/) -> Lambda function to check credentials -> Cognito (Store the credentials).**

If credentials OK I'll return the access_token to the client.

All the examples I've found is using Federated Identities, but I'm using a user pool identity.

If anyone know about how can i do it I'll be extremely grateful.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "Login via API" ? Depending on your use-case, you may want to consider using Usage Plan API Keys instead.

Comment: You can directly ask Cognito for credentials. Then, you can send ID Cognito's token to API Gateway from your client. API Gateway has Authorizers which can validate with Cognito a token sent by client. In last step you can trigger lambda functions. Whatsmore, API Gateway can pass to lambda the details from Cognito about user, like sub, email etc.

Comment: @nicq however the issue is that now you need to have S3 also in the picture. For S3 upload it requires access-token which is in a way using federated identities.